# Wordpress Search Form Issue | Misleading search URL. | Pointing to wrong URL

Tags: search

Generally,

We put `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` in the header where we desire the search form, and then later we put the custom code for HTML in searchform.php.

This is the whole [HTML](http://html.ankishpost.com/) from where I am trying to create an HTML template.

This is the Portion of an HTML

```
<li><input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
```

that was supposed to be converted into an working wordpress search.

However, I put this whole form modified a little bit with my CSS's classes →

```
        <form action="/" method="get">
            <li>
                <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
            </li>
        </form>
```

**THE PROBLEM →**
Misleading search URL.
Suppose my search string is "**ok**"

The search URL anticipated to be generated is →

[right](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/?s=ok) but it generates →

[wrong](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/?s=ok).

[Live WP Site here.](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/)

Comment: What if you change `action="/"` to `action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"`? WordPress seems to not be actually installed in site01? Make sure the settings are correct in wp-admin

Comment: WP is installed here → site01. [Proof here](https://www.screencast.com/t/xUEq9EmT)

Comment: I used your advice given, but it is now showing a blank page. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Well your search form is now pointing towards the correct url. Now you need a search.php page that loops through the found results ;)

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find a template for displaying Search Results pages. Add the code to your **search.php** file. If you have installed the **WP-PageNavi** plugin then you'll see the pagination if the search result has more than 10 items.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Search Results pages.
*/
get_header();
?>
```

`<h2><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'themedomain' ), '<strong>"' . get_search_query() . '"</strong>' ); ?></h2>

<div class="posts">
    <?php
        global $paged;
        $s = $_GET['s'];
        $post_types = array('post', 'page');
        $args=array(
            'post_type' => $post_types,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            's' => $s,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <!-- post-box -->
    <article class="post-box">
        <div class="meta">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <p><?php _e('Posted by','themedomain');?> <?php if (!get_the_author_meta('first_name') && !get_the_author_meta('last_name')) { the_author_posts_link(); } else { echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')).'">'.get_the_author_meta('first_name').' '.get_the_author_meta('last_name').'</a>'; } ?> <?php _e('&middot; on','themedomain');?> <?php echo get_the_time('F d, Y'); ?> <?php _e('&middot; in','themedomain');?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('&middot; with','themedomain');?> <?php comments_popup_link(__('0 Comments', 'themedomain'),__('1 Comment', 'themedomain'), __('% Comments', 'themedomain')); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Continue Reading &rarr;','themedomain'); ?></a></p>
    </article>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
</div>
<!-- paging -->
<div class="paging">
    <ul>
        <?php
            if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }                               
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>`

<?php get_footer(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this form based on your code:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>" method="get">
  <li>
    <input class="search" type="text" name="s" id="s" 
           placeholder="Search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
  </li>
</form>
```

Comment: I have already updated this form, but try to search anything on the live WP URL it will give an empty page.

Comment: Do you have the 'search.php' file on your theme folder?

Comment: Yes, but empty. Is there any specific code to be put on that?

Comment: Any further help will be appreciated?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: My confusion is do we require both → search.php and serachform.php because I have the later.